# SMTP sending an priority email

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to use Python's `smtplib` to set the priority of an email to high. I have successfully used this library to send email, but am unsure how to get the priority working.

```
 import smtplib
 from smtplib import SMTP
```

My first attempt was to use this from researching how to set the priority:

```
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg, priority ="high")
```

However I got an error: `keyword priority is not recognized.`

I have also tried using:

```
msg['X-MSMail-Priority'] = 'High'
```

However I get another error. Is there any way to set the priority using only smtplib?

Comment: And what is "another error" exactly? Apart from that: you're invening new API calls. The sendmail() method does not take a 'priority' parameter - why don't you check the API docs? sendmail() accepts a mail_options parameter which is a list of parameters..don't guess API, look them up.

Comment: I can not find any documentation on the web specifying the mail_options parameters! I've unsuccessfully attempted this: smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg[,mail_options=[priority="high"]])

Comment: @SarahAddis [The docs](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) clearly state that "The caller may pass a list of ESMTP options (such as 8bitmime) to be used in MAIL FROM commands as mail_options. ESMTP options (such as DSN commands) that should be used with all RCPT commands can be passed as rcpt_options." You'll have to look up in the RFCs what ESMPT options and RCPT options are.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Priority is just a matter of email content (to be exact, header content). See [here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_471.asp).

The next question would be how to put that into an email.

That completely depends how you build that email. If you use the `email` module, you would do it this way:

```
from email.Message import Message
m = Message()
m['From'] = 'me'
m['To'] = 'you'
m['X-Priority'] = '2'
m['Subject'] = 'Urgent!'
m.set_payload('Nothing.')
```

and then use it with

```
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, m.as_string())
```

Addendum for the values:

According to [this](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1188086) forum, there are the following values:

> 1 (Highest), 2 (High), 3 (Normal), 4 (Low), 5 (Lowest).
> 3 (Normal) is default if the field is omitted.

Comment: How to on "Flag" when sending a mail? I tried the above with an additional line as "m['Flag'] = '1'". I didn't get any error but the flag wasn't on either.

Comment: @zingy use priority 2, it will give your flag

Comment: @Busturdust With priority '2' only exclamation sign appeared but the flag was not enabled.

Comment: What if i want to remove the priority flag? I tried with the empty string for X-Priority header but no change.

Comment: just one question, why number 2 ?, I thought that "1" is the highest priority.

Comment: If using `EmailMessage` objects you can add extra_headers. `msg = EmaiMessage()`, `msg.extra_headers = {"X-Priority":"2"}`