# How to set Importance priority when sending email via SES using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

I'm sending emails using AWS Lambda function that calls the SES service via boto3. I managed to get everything working, however i would like to add 'important' priority on the email. Reading the boto3 api docs it does not state setting priority. Has anyone done this for SES please. Below is example of call to boto3:

```
import boto3

ses = boto3.client('ses')

email_response = ses.send_email(
        Destination={
            'BccAddresses': [
            ],
            'CcAddresses': [
            ],
            'ToAddresses': [
                email_address
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                    'Data': html_output,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Data': 'My msg'
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`send_raw_email()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_raw_email) method instead since SMTP Priority is a SES-supported customer header field, though not as a boto3 method argument.

You can read more about the SMTP Priority field in the [SMTP sending an priority email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843148/smtp-sending-an-priority-email) StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Thanks dmulter. I got it working now with send_raw_email

Comment: @RonD how do resolve the issue? can you please share the code snippet if possible, I am also want to implement the priority in email as well.